# Supplying remote data to directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When developing directives it seems best practice to seperate the data / model from the actual directive.

For example if i have a directive called "Event" e.g.

```
<div class="event">
    <h1>{event.title}</h1>
    <small>{event.startDate}</small>
</div>
```

**what is the best way to supply data to directives in the most reusable pattern? through a service?**

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot that you can do with Directives. They are a lot of ways you can work with the data. The more direct way is to pass the data or references into your directive. Take a look at the link below for reference. As an example to your code, I would do the following:

```
<div dir-event event-title="context.title" event-start="context.startDate" ></div>
```

in the HTML, where context.title and context.startDate are objects on your controller. Then for the directive:

```
App.directive("dirEvent", function() {
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            title:"=",
            startDate:"="
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class='event'><h1>{{title}}</h1><small>{{startDate}}</small></div>",
        replace: true
    }
});
```

[Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)